# How do I get the addresses from the Ganache?

Tags: solidity, remix, ganache

I am trying to implement a **virtual** Smart Voting in Remix IDE.

I want to get the remaining 99 addresses from the ***Ganache*** to create an iteration and have them register at polling stations and then vote.

How do I get these addresses?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ganache, you can click on the settings button:

[image]

Then on the Accounts & Keys button and set the TOTAL ACCOUNTS TO GENERATE value to 100:

[image]

Then, you can use `web3` to get an array with all the accounts:

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");

const web3 = new Web3("http://127.0.0.1:7545");

web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts) => {
  console.log("accounts: ", accounts);
});
```

In my case, it returned:

```js
[
  '0xcb21123cD81A08B754735712e099a5Ed5e7748e3',
  '0x520D209015098CC4D9797183e9F9305AbfFa5870',
  '0xdfDa1e966F26E93FFdEfb589fdf66A30f953a0aC',
  '0xD98A293Ca55b8D3f791327ade3e07880f099451c',
  '0x1827b4Ab3769df679A1BaAB75591C787D89770C9',
  '0xCbCC0339969593BA7BdA79fAf34993dD8A52B481',
  '0xfdEe4cE8B0Fd655fA079A22445feA29E5342593b',
  '0x86466bf947510c5F3798e4bfeE9031aaBedC89E2',
  '0x685908bFde40cE2e57a8EcA3Ce6251D0F157616C',
  '0xFd4152bb8138Af7be842765Ee6DBeaAC2093f2f7',
  '0x8be98fc957A113AF65CFf11CDECc7F463C5505c2',
  '0x4222DbAfa498C3116995FA924d0F0551B94f51A5',
  '0xf13BF546f8D54524E3B2ADe22C68832991b8f77a',
  '0xf11efc833E829091AE6922CdC729f38277ad22c1',
  '0xAA7C92c66E2aD7d32B9e2053a1Db8154B420E538',
  '0x797461AE98AD5eb234b68b295Ae8F8Ee9FfAe9bf',
  '0x84A0bB7A97fa7737a3144a76222E25EE7B96a0e6',
  '0x0FFf1a9A172AB40aFf518883231d5508a6e69eA4',
  '0xddb693bDA0d0bE777195444186e474109181f290',
  '0xFCC281748e66EA6d8a50Bcf3Bb21DEb8aC67B773',
  '0xf16f23934369e8D39C9919925f60D829173cB17f',
  '0x65bBCa00980721Dbd3c07D312d9303562B4F95C0',
  '0x427D5cbc30D944EB470AFbef3078Ac6d47166d7C',
  '0x203a32d4f3959A7646Bd42d335A78d817923058a',
  '0x5025f7Ac76eF2Fb93956ce98a4bf7FdCDaDAc00b',
  '0x33deEDFcB2C5296fd7A5E6e811Ac5e835D8A9c41',
  '0x331651bF97A46818Ea6553F08589010CC3435EA9',
  '0x3F33E9018d666B2A4c52567d9C6919c02A1f6389',
  '0xCebe1F74B38e7b26849dcBFc660F11931c559535',
  '0x4323e51939daD78de33ACa92D6b2E761ca8F7A44',
  '0xBcfc3DdEf7eE7A18AF7F8d2B9f3b73Ffc1Df176A',
  '0xE25af33EB7A658B62de495F7249715c5Bc2d2036',
  '0x9Dd5F7B2C9df7A6f2Fc38D38ef52618b56Faccb4',
  '0x75772b1cb54164E7634D582D982b664053dEC701',
  '0x7093993aD560a439fAe313f771E7899D10F10E4b',
  '0xF71716876c355C99da56467758195A23E9edB0E9',
  '0xb8F84fF8a4b8B6F0d37afFF5556118803880D17A',
  '0xb23a82F85f95c6DC3a277A2DBA02E9CFd20D8B0f',
  '0x6c4Ab420c9E178D470Fc829D9Dc49e82296d54bd',
  '0x27e0E996273fF9C7cEc8Eb94c165726c6eFc0147',
  '0x33b3Cb9eE7130608918F70C5c93dd710b72151a5',
  '0x887409002C5C8D95D6036572eFD2d564689D6Ec4',
  '0xAC30F961551Bd8c7bb70f2e36d04904c6F1Ba739',
  '0xa41e3400E8EeE0C5C4191E5c161B7FCc865131e7',
  '0x68dbd6607ba4965434c7072Dc2C990b9BaBD21a1',
  '0x8928D01D14Ec13f9350710A234Eb27BBfb87A1C6',
  '0xEECD9Fb5e4407F8C8519D487659Bba8224b17009',
  '0xc12B6F6Df80f5Df669e976C920A3B0F560ecfEe1',
  '0xE45bED92a7CDf9f1B16dF31500084B94F9429247',
  '0xac7a859046382BF85E800FD2a705E0965C4d3125',
  '0xcFD6a0f7495502a1d04EE4c1B594DA51cf1A6C8c',
  '0x8d32BBe6960D16C1fC0baaC28d53193EDE466d36',
  '0xf76CeBBD5e47018ff731E02dBbf5423398cf0d4B',
  '0x4E1178C9d2b2E02C6B56D8877b890D0ff80cc048',
  '0x649F4e6dBbD51b5F9bf82e2De30335DAC276585E',
  '0x7F798fd4795fDaBd05fD98907046548e98a24471',
  '0x806552e28574cA95a29684ce325586D8a94c50a4',
  '0x1F152a96217788F1816c0A3340f17700a8Ba9821',
  '0x4688dfF7688aFCaf99F3e9c1ADC5608bd719642E',
  '0xfaa675eD00948c878658D051087D5BdA94B538B0',
  '0xf666c9CE798DED1CaEEbcf977099B00bfBEFEAAe',
  '0x5c098ff352a653ed9897D8a1ae41b990a9b29bb8',
  '0x2968f823629C468132b42644EFfD4d77bb970bCD',
  '0x47e7e4A2A25E3181957FC76Ccb2C4851B67eE575',
  '0x2f4Fb29dC9FAE0a4E3cB6661F858a2AACCbA81d9',
  '0xBaE9f00612F16cFac2D02c74891351024C5D38fa',
  '0xa90F527cEEd0bD90D5300A37a5bEbDF919862C65',
  '0x4D847040D58F96941d9c2fb34a6a1E6491A8B2aC',
  '0x7bE7E3ff9925054e553263b506c739a2AE55b84d',
  '0xE38b7b65337CFF3F1db09febCE7d43A1bC257552',
  '0x9c10d2bb11af54F3443C420dF9072177102B96C4',
  '0x05F4Fdd33474a4Bd56744f9aBa799277f808Db48',
  '0xF011eee2638B1A2988E0a0115688665eC3dA27c9',
  '0x742b61D97f6bD7fC403c9162874B5eA13A5b2f3b',
  '0x046f6a982C84816d8f54C3A7935D52B50f8fDA35',
  '0xa025fa7E2dfc7B33bd5ed9107DE0dcEdad0529A8',
  '0xaf7Bb0E651D8a36Be89eAbCE4D6419728F389fb2',
  '0xd3C98E67559Be1944E7497bfEF5F3a49bE2b4e31',
  '0x3382f8361d1005785fcc78351a44fb9aAf4CEC2E',
  '0x9616f596cEd138C1B9FD1f6F784B6ADF3adC593E',
  '0xB0A755761C63CBe86C15905A0b7a40C3a2033000',
  '0xCbaF8F9FC2b6c76ac6dc45fBD563D12bBAd99ebf',
  '0x2d3F177Af44a94820824dC6eA51C0bb44D7f12FA',
  '0xB246f6266a96AbB4dc19a2B9F36A199443E37DB9',
  '0xca2930F1F6B8caC276d390b1693FBFDF738FE0aa',
  '0x7f3BA300Ea1Ac5AE9e62Efb0ED5DBeDE75687566',
  '0xb39EEFA6344b022AD3Ab22c5752062256A44671D',
  '0x966e73f3E67cf2580254Ec9f0D64C246184a4058',
  '0xe5D5378d394eE93C7d28AC65bd90760686A8f138',
  '0x2B3940b944B530233301C4bE9329485316E0C7BC',
  '0xf337402D16340079485C1e5BFdeC2AF71fde55F2',
  '0x033EA26B11D7608D061aB3E76C1553f222D3BAa6',
  '0x5772C785072B5bAA3DA6DDce9A78eD3B55B062Fe',
  '0x708E9913a515dE216F758fabd6574eAA9416Cd61',
  '0x994d8a1E43a5dE3f12B79602AF38Df268Ba0d060',
  '0xE8e6dadC6E18d47f36eDDF63457e18679AB2598A',
  '0x4961F86DBF240BFDaa141D8659289e8E174c8084',
  '0xace54FcFae6967BdF0A9BecfCF60c8c23dFcDC1B',
  '0xb920DCF7F525766927A5fA26062fEeF33fAaf787',
  '0x777429AcDBE49d6FFBcf4Ab2Ffd8e78ea94ac940'
]
```

Let me know if that helped.

For receiving an array of addresses in your contract and doing something with it, you can try:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

contract Contract {

    address[] public addresses;

    function getAddresses() public view returns(address[] memory) {
        return addresses;
    }

    // Adds one address to the storage addresses array 
    function addAddress(address addr) public {
        addresses.push(addr);
    }

    // Replaces the storage addresses with this new array of addresses
    function addAddresses(address[] calldata _addresses) public {
        addresses = _addresses;
    }

    // Does something on an array of address passed
    function operate(address[] calldata _addresses) public pure {

        for(uint256 i = 0; i < _addresses.length; i++) {
            address addr = _addresses[i];
            // do something with addr
        }

    }

    // Does something on the storage array of addresses
    function operateOnStorageArrayOfAddresses() public view {
        // Makes a copy of the storage address in memory to save gas
        address[] memory addressesCopy = addresses;
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < addressesCopy.length; i++) {
            address addr = addressesCopy[i];
            // do something with addr
        }

    }

}
```

To interact with the contract from `web3` sending and receiving the addresses, you can do:

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");

const web3 = new Web3("http://127.0.0.1:7545");

web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts) => {
  // console.log("accounts: ", accounts);
});

const abi = [
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "address",
        name: "addr",
        type: "address",
      },
    ],
    name: "addAddress",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "address[]",
        name: "_addresses",
        type: "address[]",
      },
    ],
    name: "addAddresses",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "",
        type: "uint256",
      },
    ],
    name: "addresses",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "address",
        name: "",
        type: "address",
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "getAddresses",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "address[]",
        name: "",
        type: "address[]",
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "address[]",
        name: "_addresses",
        type: "address[]",
      },
    ],
    name: "operate",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "pure",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "operateOnStorageArrayOfAddresses",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
];

const contractAddress = "0x99Aeb08Ab2fD121138D02F0e5b20D57e0a3a6082";

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress, {
  from: "0xcb21123cD81A08B754735712e099a5Ed5e7748e3",
  gas: 3000000,
});

async function sendAndGetAddresses() {
  const addresses = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  await contract.methods.addAddresses(addresses).send();

  const retrievedAddressesFromTheContract = await contract.methods
    .getAddresses()
    .call();

  console.log("retrievedAddresses: ", retrievedAddressesFromTheContract);
}

sendAndGetAddresses();
```

Comment: This is for javascript, right? (Also, it works.)
Through Solidity how do I get the addresses?

Comment: Through Solidity, you can't get those addresses. You will need to send them to your solidity contract. You can create a function in your contract that accepts an array of addresses and then you do the operations that you need on them.
Smart contracts don't have access to the real world as regular software has.

Comment: Okay then, how is this done?

Comment: Take a look at the update on the answer.

Comment: Where does the getAddress() method come from? I have an error. `const retrievedAddressesFromTheContract = await contract.methods
    .getAddresses()
    .call();
`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update that. Check the code again.